# RAILS : how to define scope with date range from column values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to create a named scope in which I would like to receive records which are only updated within the first week after they are created.
As you can see I receive an error message for the column name created_at.

```
scope :shortlived, where("updated_at < ?", (created_at+7.days))


undefined local variable or method `created_at' for #<Class:0xb184725c>
```

I will appreciate if you can inform me what might be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is similar to the answers posted here. if you're using postgreSQL, you can just compare the difference with '7 days' interval

```
scope :shortlived, -> { where("(updated_at - created_at) < '7 days'") }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something database specific. For example for MySQL:

```
scope :shortlived, -> { where('updated_at < created_at + interval 3 day') }
```